# Conversion from _Ty to int warning in MSVC accumulate

Tags: c++, visual-c++, boost

I cranked up MSVC warnings to level 4 and have a problem using accumulate over boost::circular_buffer. This code:

```
boost::circular_buffer<unsigned short> shorts;
shorts.resize(10);
unsigned short res = std::accumulate(shorts.begin(), shorts.end(), static_cast<unsigned short>(0));
```

Fail with a `possible loss of data` warning in the accumulate template (numeric):

```
// FUNCTION TEMPLATE accumulate
template<class _InIt,
    class _Ty,
    class _Fn>
    _NODISCARD inline _Ty accumulate(const _InIt _First, const _InIt _Last, _Ty _Val, _Fn _Reduce_op)
    {   // return noncommutative and nonassociative reduction of _Val and all in [_First, _Last), using _Reduce_op
    _Adl_verify_range(_First, _Last);
    auto _UFirst = _Get_unwrapped(_First);
    const auto _ULast = _Get_unwrapped(_Last);
    for (; _UFirst != _ULast; ++_UFirst)
        {
        _Val = _Reduce_op(_Val, *_UFirst); // <-- THIS IS WHERE THE WARNING IS
        }

    return (_Val);
    }
```

Any ideas what might be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**25.9.2 Accumulate [accumulate]** defines effect of `std::accumulate` as `acc = std::move(acc) + *i`. Since C++ for some reason does not support arithmetic operations on integer types smaller than `int` and instead promotes arguments on both sides of `+` into `int` prior to summing, result will be an `int`. Therefore you are getting a seemingly unavoidable warning here.

A possible workaround would be to define accumulator to be `unsinged int` and then cast final result to the desired type:

```
unsigned short res{static_cast< unsigned short >(::std::accumulate(shorts.begin(), shorts.end(), 0u));
```